# Angular2 rc4 asynchronous testing

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm having problems verifying that an asynchronous method was called while testing. Here is a simple example.

```
describe('async test', () => {

     it('promise should resolve', async(() => {

         let resolve = jasmine.createSpy('resolve').and.callFake((n) => {
             expect(n).toEqual(1);
         });

         let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(1);
         });

         promise.then(resolve);
         expect(resolve).toHaveBeenCalled();

     }));

});
```

This test fails because the final expect to check if the resolve was called is executed before the promise resolves. If I remove the final expect then there is no way to verify that the promise resolves naturally. Here is an example that should fail but does not.

```
describe('async test', () => {

     it('promise should resolve', async(() => {

         let resolve = jasmine.createSpy('resolve').and.callFake((n) => {
             expect(n).toEqual(1);
         });

         let promise = new Promise(() => {});

         promise.then(resolve);

     }));

 });
```

Since the expect is in the resolve that is never called the test passes even though it shouldn't since the resolve was never called. From my understanding Angular2's async() method should not complete in till all asynchronous methods have completed however, this doesn't seem to be the case. I could use Jasmine2's done function however, this doesn't seem to interact well will tests that require inject() or async() to be called.

Comment: I'm coming across the exact problem. async function seems not to wait for all async tasks at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9815) it is a matter of dependencies loading order.

As @choeller indicates, I changed my karma.conf.js so system-polyfills.js file is loaded before zone.js and my unit began to work. However, I could not make your snipped work. I guess it is because they are a proof of concept rather than a real unit test, are they?

Anyway, hope this helps you out.